# importError: learnig curve and Optimizer don't exist more (python)?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn

when l try to import  learning_ curve it doesnt work.
l succeeded to import all the files in sklearn  except learning curves . For instance :
from sklearn.cluster import bicluter   (it's working)
from sklearn import  cross_validation (it's working)
**from sklearn import learning_curve (not working )**
here is the import error

File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: cannot import name learning_curve

**The same thing for import Optimizer**
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named Optimizer

Comment: Is this complete trace of error ? If there is any additional info then post it. Also are you able to import sklearn completely ?

Comment: have you tried this form `from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve`?

Comment: for import Optimizer it's ok l fixed it. but for from sklearnn import learning curve still not working . Yes l can import sklearn completely  (import sklearn) ,  from sklearn.cluster import bicluster , from sklearn import cross_validation but when it comes to from sklearn import learning_curve it's not working  . the error is  :  from sklearn import learning_curve
ImportError: cannot import name learning_curve

Comment: looking at different version of sklearn there is no sub-folder called learning_curve, actually learning_curve is a file in sklearn. so to import it we just need to do from sklearn import learning_curve (but it's not working) and from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve (not working also , and l think the reason that there is no sub-folder callded learning_curve)

Comment: `sklearn.learning_curve.learning_curve` [Deprecated since version 0.18: This module will be removed in 0.20.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.learning_curve.learning_curve.html#sklearn-learning-curve-learning-curve)